# How can I play a custom sound after a button has been clicked in my Xcode app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delay

I am using Xcode to create a `Mac OSX, Objective-C, cocoa app.` I want my app to play a custom sound after a certain time.

This is what my code looks like:

`- (IBAction)clickToPlayCustomSoundButtonClicked {`

`[self performSelector:@selector(playCustomSound) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];`

`}`

`- (void)playCustomSound {`

`***This is where I want to put the code to play the custom sound***`

`}`

What code should I put in my `(void)playCustomSound` method to play a custom sound?

Please help and thanks guys :D

Comment: I don't think you want a sound to play when a button is clicked in Xcode, but when it is clicked in the app you are developing? Xcode is the development environment.

Comment: Oops! Means the same to me... I know you can't play sound from the design environment, but I just say Xcode... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming your sound-file is in your Ressources folder):

```
NSSound *player = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyCustomSound" ofType:@"mp3"] byReference:NO];
[player play];
```